# remove duplicates from array

Tags: array, fastest-code, fastest-algorithm, algorithm

You have given an array from which we need to remove duplicates.

Rules:

1. First or immediate duplicates gets removed first.
2. Array contains natural numbers `a[i]>0 for i>=0`
3. no. of elements in the array is greater than 1 i.e. `n>1`

e.g.

```
{1,2,3,4,5,5,4,6,6,7,8}=> {1,2,3,7,8}
{1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,7,8} => {1,2,4,5,6,8}
{1,1,3,3,4,4,6,6}=>{}
{4,2,6,8,3,1,1,3,8,6,2,4}=>{}
{6,6,6,1}=>{6,1}
```

Only adjacent duplicate elements like `[1, 2, 2, 1]` are removed, but not `[1, 2, 1, 2]`. This process is repeated until no further modifications are made.

For winning criteria is the one which gives the fastest result.

Comment: You must specify the winning criterion clearly in your post.

Comment: Should `{6,6,6,1}` output `{1}` or `{1,6}`? Add this on the test-case, maybe?

Comment: @officialaimm, It should output `{6,1}`.

Comment: Why `{6,1}`? `6` is a duplicate. Then, `{1,2,3,4,5,5,4,6,6,7,8}` should output `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}` as well.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder, first matching duplicates gets removed. so next 6 is not having any immediate matching element so first 6's will be removed and `6,1` is remaining in the result. hope this helped

Comment: @SatishPatel You should specify that in the challenge.

Comment: Also, I suggest making it [tag:code-golf].

Comment: Code golf *or* fastest code please, not both. And if it is a code golf, please say it in your question, not with the tags.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing, thanks for the suggestion. edited as required.

Comment: [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/fastest-code/info) and [fastest-algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/fastest-algorithm/info) don't go together.

Comment: Does the returned array need to be sorted?

Comment: @powelles `{6,1}` is not sorted...

Comment: @HyperNeutrino But it still follows the order of the original array. I guess I mean does the sort order matter at all.

Comment: @powelles Ah okay. We'll wait for OP clarification then. I don't think it matters too much since even if it increases byte count that doesn't matter, but there could be some optimizations, so I don't know for sure.

Comment: If you want to keep this as fastest ode (which is fine) you'll need to provide larger test cases as yours would complete almost instantaneous in any sane language and be subject to significant noise in times

Comment: Often problems with (simple) polynomial-time algorithm is not suitable for fastest-code.

Comment: Next time, please consider using [the Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/).

Comment: @musicman523, thanks for your feedback. I will make sure next time post question on sandbox first then on the main page. thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 201 bytes

```python
array = input()
index = 0
while index < len(array) - 1:
	if index >= 0 and array[index] == array[index + 1]:
		array = array[:index] + array[index + 2:]
		index -= 1
		continue
	index += 1
print(array)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY5BCoMwEEXX5hR/qVihsTtpehHJQmqKARlDiLSePp0mKZTCLPL@f8PEHWHZqI9x8n46oGDJ7aFuhKXZvJjP4rnY1SDzFauhOrkNOshBVPZRuhvLmGhGqscUaij1y2ghNS9V33O5G4rc/rn9oNnN1ClIhvtGwdJuRInbT@y8pVC@FeMoT@jT8OOi3w)

Optimizations thanks to Mr. Xcoder

Comment: I got values between `1.1126001481898129e-05` and `8.827599958749488e-05` for the test cases in the challenge.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Okay, thanks. This is using bash's built in `time` which may be off, I don't know for sure.

Comment: I get slightly better times if I add `continue` at the end of your if statement and drop the `else` (between `1.0405001376057044e-05` and `4.7165998694254085e-05`), because it skips the evaluation of the `else`-statement.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Interesting, thanks.